# How to replace multiple elements with the same element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, replacewith

I am trying to make the Hangman game in the browser. I generate a random word, then display one empty box for each letter of the word, and the user will be able to click a button with a letter to try to guess if the random word contains this letter. If it does,  then all empty boxes representing that letter get replaced with a box with that letter written inside.

My problem is, if the word generated contains the letter clicked multiple times, only the last occurrence gets replaced in the end, which I figured would be caused by my wrong usage of jQuery's 'replaceWith'. I hope I didn't make this sound too complicated, if you have any question, please ask away!

So here is my code:

```
// Get all occurences of the clicked letter and push their positions into array

  function letterClicked(id) {
    var positionsOfLetter = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
      if (randomWord[i] == id) {
        positionsOfLetter.push(i);
      }
    }
    // Replace each box at position that contains the letter clicked with a box containing the letter clicked

    positionsOfLetter.forEach(position => {
      $('#' + position).replaceWith($("#" + id));
    });
  }
```

Comment: You're going to have to clone the element you want repeated.  `replaceWith(existingDomElement)` is going to move the existing element to the new place, not clone it

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: Do you use duplicated id's to identify the letters? If so that's your problem. I'd need to be unique. Will be a lot easier to help you if you show your html. Or even better create a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This row

`$('#' + position).replaceWith($("#" + id));`

returns the same element every time, causing it to move around until it settles at the last iteration of the loop. replacing it with

`$('#' + position).replaceWith($("#" + id).clone());`

should do the trick.